# Extract all lines from an SVG object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I am trying to extract all the lines from an SVG object so that they can be rendered by a special rasterizer, but it turned out to be way trickier than I imagined.

Main challenges are that:

- The svg `<line>` and `<polyline>` elements can sometimes be contained within a `<defs>` group, that is rendered by  elements. These would need flattening.
- The `<path>` element would also need converting into line elements.  I would be happy to throw away fancy curved lines and just stick to the straight ones.

Is there an easy way to do this, or some code that already exists to save re-inventing the wheel?  I'm working in Javascript.

Thanks!

Comment: So to be clear, you need only `<line>` , `<polyline>` and `path` elements? no need for other shapes?

Comment: Yea, although I imagine rect etc are not too hard to decompose into lines if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answer Kaiido!  Much appreciated! The reason for this is that I need to use a custom rasteriser for the SVG that corrects for certain image distortions. It is not used in a traditional web context.

The approach below breaks down paths into line segments using two functions.  One function `_samplePath` can sample points along an arbitrary SVG path. The other 
`pathToLines` is able to inspect each path and generate (more efficiently, for certain paths) the needed line segments.  For the paths that contain besiers, arcs, and other wierdnesses that would take a lot of time to support `pathToLines` drops back to `_samplePath`.

This is based on a few samples I found on SO.

```js
/**
 * Take an SVG path and use a sampling technique to break it down into line segments.
 * @param The path element.
 * @param The list of lines to write into. Default is to create a new list and return it.
 * @param The number of samples to take. Default is length / 2.
 * @return The resulting list of line segment.
 */
function _samplePath(path, lines, samples) {
 
 var length  = path.getTotalLength();
 lines = lines || []
 samples = samples || length / 3;
 var segSize = length / samples;
 
 var last_pt = path.getPointAtLength(0);
 for (var i = 0; i < samples; ++i) {
  
  // Compute the next sample point.
  var pt = path.getPointAtLength(segSize * i);
  
  // If this sample point is over a certain size relative to the segSize, we have hit a m/M and jumped.
  //  Thus we should not render this bit...
  if (Math.pow(last_pt.x - pt.x, 2) + Math.pow(last_pt.y - pt.y, 2) < (segSize*segSize*2))
   lines.push({ x1: last_pt.x, y1: last_pt.y, x2: pt.x, y2: pt.y })
  
  // Next line please.
  last_pt = pt;
 }
 
 // Last line.
 var pt = path.getPointAtLength(length);
 lines.push({ x1: last_pt.x, y1: last_pt.y, x2: pt.x, y2: pt.y })
 
 // Return the lines.
 return lines;
}

/**
 * Take any SVG path element and flatten it into a line list in absolute coordinates.
 * @param path The SVG path element to flatten and segment.
 * @param The list of lines to write into. Default is to create a new list and return it.
 * @return The list of line segements.
 */
function pathToLines(path, lines) {
 
 // Init.
 var xl, yl, x0, y0, x1, y1, x2, y2, segs = path.pathSegList;
 var segs = path.pathSegList;
 lines = lines || [];
 if (segs.length <= 1) return lines;
 
 // Rendering functions.
 function emitLine(x, y) { lines.push({ x1: xl, y1: yl, x2: x, y2: y }); xl = x; yl = y; } 
 //function emitArc(x, y, rx, ry, large, sweep, segmentsize) { }
 
 // If we have weird objects I don't want to support by hand...
 //   Handle as a complex path with a given number of samples.
 for (var i = 0, len = segs.numberOfItems; i < len; i++) { 
  if (/[csqtaCSQTA]/.test(segs.getItem(i).pathSegTypeAsLetter))
   return _samplePath(path, lines);
 }
 
 // Otherwise, parse the path for a more accurate and optimal experience.
    for (var x = 0, y = 0, i = 0, len = segs.numberOfItems; i < len; i++)
 {
  var seg = segs.getItem(i);
  var c = seg.pathSegTypeAsLetter;
  
  // Handle absolute coordinates.
  if (/[MLHVCSQTA]/.test(c)) {
   if ('x' in seg) x = seg.x;
   if ('y' in seg) y = seg.y;
  }
  
  // Handle relative coordinates.
  else
  {
   //if ('x1' in seg) x1 = seg.x1 + x;
   //if ('x2' in seg) x2 = seg.x2 + x;
   //if ('y1' in seg) y1 = seg.y1 + y;
   //if ('y2' in seg) y2 = seg.y2 + y;
   if ('x'  in seg) x += seg.x;
   if ('y'  in seg) y += seg.y;
  }
  
  switch (c)
  {
   case 'm': case 'M': x0=x, y0=y; xl=x; yl=y;   break;  // MoveTo (just skip)
   case 'l': case 'L': emitLine(x, y);     break;  // LineTo (emit)
   case 'h': case 'H': emitLine(x, yl);     break;  // LineToHorizontalAbs (emit with y0)
   case 'v': case 'V': emitLine(xl, y);             break;  // LinetoVerticalAbs (emit with x0)
   case 'z': case 'Z': emitLine(x0, y0);     break;  // Move back to zero (close the line).
   
   // Flatten an arc efficiently?
   //case 'a': case 'A': console.log("Arc: " + seg);  break;
   
   
  }
 }
 
 return lines;
}
```

The other part of the question relating to `<use>` and `<defs>` used the SVG matracies .

```js
// Get the use element and its target transformation matrix t0.
var element = $("use").get(0);
var link = use[i].getAttribute("xlink:href")
var t0 = use[i].getScreenCTM();

// Find the source element and its current transformation matrix t1.
//  This is not the same as the <use> element, because the inners are offset in the <defs>.
var defLink = $(svg).find(link);
var t1 = defLink.get(0).getCTM();

// Then use this function to transform each point on the line by the returned SVGMatrix.
function transformSVGPoint(point, matrix) {
  return {
    x: point.x * matrix.a + point.y * matrix.c + matrix.e,
    y: point.x * matrix.b + point.y * matrix.d + matrix.f
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Second point first :
**Transforming your curved pathes to straight ones :**
At this point, it doesn't transform it to `<line>` elements, but it should not be too difficult to do it so, and I'm not sure you really need this.

```js
function simplifyPathes(svg) {
  var pathes = svg.querySelectorAll('path');
  for (i = 0; i < pathes.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < pathes[i].pathSegList.numberOfItems; j++) {
      var segment = pathes[i].pathSegList.getItem(j);
      if (segment.pathSegType > 4) {
        if (segment.pathSegType & 1) {
          var newSeg = pathes[i].createSVGPathSegLinetoRel(segment.x, segment.y);
        } else {
          var newSeg = pathes[i].createSVGPathSegLinetoAbs(segment.x, segment.y);
        }
        pathes[i].pathSegList.replaceItem(newSeg, j);
      }
    }
  }
}

setTimeout(function(){simplifyPathes(document.querySelector('svg'))}, 1500);
```

```html
<svg width="600" height="300" viewBox="0 0 600 300" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <path id="path" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M286,81c-70.7,14-134.3-57.3-91.3-2.7s145,74.7,53,74.3 C155.7,152.3,150,16,164.3,93c14.3,77-33.7,68.7,53,87s-23.7,31.7-123,6.3-52,86-150,0" />
  </defs>
  <path fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M161,88.7c-3.3,44-58.4-5.7-58.4-5.7s-41-31,49.4-31.7 c90.3-0.7,86-61.3,83.7,2.7c-2.3,64,54.3,57.3-19.3,71.6S-27,47.7,89,110.7s107.7,152.7,106.7,65.7" />
  <use xlink:href="#path" transform="translate(75, 25)" />
</svg>
```

*There might be a better way, but I don't have it yet.*
[**Some readings here**](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#InterfaceSVGPathSegList)
You may want to combine it with some library like [simplify.js](http://mourner.github.io/simplify-js/).

**Now, the first part of the question.**
I'll assume that if `<use>` elements are a problem, it is because of [Gecko's restrictive rules on external resources in svg Images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/SVG_as_an_Image#Restrictions).
If it is not the case, I'm curious about why you need "flattening".

I wrote an horrible hack that may show you a way for a workaround.

```js
function cloneUses(svg) {
  var uses = svg.querySelectorAll('use')
  for (i = 0; i < uses.length; i++) {
 var elem = uses[i],
  id = elem.getAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'href').substring(1),
   c = svg.getElementById(id).cloneNode(true),
   b = elem.transform.baseVal,
   a = elem.attributes;
 if(b.length>1){
  b.consolidate();
  c.transform.baseVal.appendItem(b.getItem(0));
  c.transform.baseVal.consolidate();
  }
 for (j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
   if (a[j].value !== ('#' + id) && a[j].value !== "transform") {
  c.setAttribute(a[j].name, a[j].value);
   }
 }
 elem.parentNode.insertBefore(c, elem);
 elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
  }
}
setTimeout(function(){cloneUses(document.querySelector('svg'))}, 1500);
```

```html
<svg width="600" height="300" viewBox="0 0 600 300" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <line id="line" stroke="black" x1="72" y1="120" x2="25" y2="25" />
    <path id="path" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M286,81c-70.7,14-134.3-57.3-91.3-2.7s145,74.7,53,74.3 C155.7,152.3,150,16,164.3,93c14.3,77-33.7,68.7,53,87s-23.7,31.7-123,6.3-52,86-150,0" />
  </defs>
  <use xlink:href="#path" transform="translate(75, 25)" />
  <use xlink:href="#line" transform="translate(125, 0)" />
</svg>
```

*Look at the svg through your browser's inspector*

Ps: I'll let you find a way to transform `<circle>`into `<line>` by yourself.

Comment: Thanks very much for this, it was very helpful.  I will post part of mine below as reference for others in these parts.